# Get motionX and motionY for simple bullets

Tags: java, math

Simple question, how would I find the angle motionX and motionY(added to the projectiles x and y each tick) to reach a point. I have the starting point, in x and y, and the target point, in x and y.

Thanks.

Comment: Depends a lot on the physical environment the bullet is moving in.  (Gravity straight down, out in space with big planets around, etc.)

Comment: In a space defined by Riemann tensor, apparently...

Comment: Should have specified that there is no gravity, no factors that can move the bullet off course.

Comment: So the bullet moves in a straight line from a to b with constant velocity, right?

Comment: Yeah, a straight line from point a to point b at a constant rate (I.E the motionX and motionY never change).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simply:

```
double motionX = (double)(endX - startX)/ticksToGetBulletAcross;
double motionY = (double)(endY - startY)/ticksToGetBulletAcross;
double angleInRadians = Math.atan(motiony/motionX);
double angleInDegrees = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(motiony/motionX));
```

Beware of rounding errors!

Comment: Think you mean endY and startY when you set motionY. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

In vector form:

```
displacementVec = (targetPoint - startPoint).normalized() * bulletSpeedPerFrame
```

This will give you 3d as well, should the need ever arise.